# Magento 2 missing component listingToolbar

Tags: magento2, migration

I'm getting this error in Magento 2 (after successfully migrated from 1.7.0.2):

> The requested component ("listingToolbar") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.

Anyone who experienced this bug?

Comment: Run `php bin/magento list` will guide though error

Comment: How? This command just list all the possibilities. It's in Magento admin sales/order i get this error.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, that listingToolbar component appear in Magento just starting from 2.1 version.

This mean some of your extensions are not compatible with your Magento version